# Is there a way to ask Apache Bench to test the response time of ALL resources served to a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, apachebench

I am load testing a node.js website. The url I am testing gets its HTML, then also tries to get another x image resources. Is it possible to tell Apache Bench to load all of these resources as part of the load testing?

Obviously I can load the HTML, then test the loading of the images separately. However, it would be nice to have a more efficient strategy for doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using that tool, no. `ab` is a very rudimentary load testing tool; it isn't really even intended as a benchmark, and it certainly doesn't have the sort of sophistication to detect and download subresources.

There are other tools that can track that information, though. One of them is the Network tab in the Chrome web inspector (or YSlow for Firebug); another is [Show Slow](http://www.showslow.com/).